# What is Joomla article options stored table?

Tags: articles, database

I am searching where in the database (table, column) are stored the choices we make at Option tab, when editing an article.
To be more specific I was looking to see where is the "Show Author" (Show Global, Show, Hide) choice is saved.
I looked at xxxx_content table but I was not able to find it there.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data you are looking for is available in same table (#__content)
and you will find all the options in **attribs** column.

> - Note that in MySQL the table will have the db table prefix that you have specified for your database during installation/db creation).

And here all the values are storing in the **JSON** format.

```
{
    "show_title":"",
    "link_titles":"",
    "show_tags":"",
    "show_intro":"",
    "info_block_position":"",
    "show_category":"",
    "link_category":"",
    "show_parent_category":"",
    "link_parent_category":"",
    "show_author":"",
    "link_author":"",
    "show_create_date":"",
    "show_modify_date":"",
    "show_publish_date":"",
    "show_item_navigation":"",
    "show_icons":"",
    "show_print_icon":"",
    "show_email_icon":"",
    "show_vote":"",
    "show_hits":"",
    "show_noauth":"",
    "urls_position":"",
    "alternative_readmore":"",
    "article_layout":"",
    "show_publishing_options":"",
    "show_article_options":"",
    "show_urls_images_backend":"",
    "show_urls_images_frontend":""
}
```

Values description -
values are stored in `0,1` format where

```
show : 1
hide : 0
use global : ""
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I was looking there but when making changes the column was not changing. I made a local test and it worked, so I have to check the database. Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome :)